# Magento 2 - Disable cash on delivery based on cod

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2, php-7, quoteitem

How to  disable cash on delivery payment based on cod availability.
**etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Model\Cashondelivery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" /> </type>
```

**Cashondelivery.php**

```
 public function aroundIsAvailable(\Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $result = $proceed();
        $zipCode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($zipCode) ? "yes" : "no";
        if ($codAvailability == 'no') {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Its not working in backend...Any modification in my code .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use below plugin for same

```
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList">
        <plugin name="methodlist" type="Module\NameSpace\Plugin\Model\Method\Available" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
```

In that class

```
 public function aroundGetAvailableMethods($object, callable $proceed,$quote)
    {
         $result = $proceed($quote);
        foreach($result as $key=>$_result){
            if($_result->getCode() == "cashondelivery"){ //make sure your payment method code
                $isAllowed = $this->_pincodeModel->isCODAvailable($quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()) ? "1" : ""           
                if(!$isAllowed)
                {
                    unset($result[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: its working for backend?

Comment: yes it will work

Comment: how to get zipcode in backend

Comment: please check code

Comment: is that works or not?

Comment: work perfect!!!!